# Entropy of a column of data set

Tags: r

I have a data set with 9 variables, I need to calculate the entropy of all the variables. I am using R and the package for entropy calculation is "entropy"
This is the code I have used:

```
entropy_variables<-array(0,dim=c(1,number of columns)
for(n in seq(1,number of columns)
{
entropy_variables[n]<-entropy(data[,n]
}
```

Is this correct?
Kindly help.